# Can I run a 24V motor with a 12V PSU

Tags: power-supply, motor, dc

Im using one BTS7960 driver to control a motor. The motor i have is  24V 500watt. If i use a 12V psu will it draw more current?

Comment: Depending on the motor it may not spin at all. Please specify more details concerning the motor by editing your original question.

Answer (score 1):

If the control in implemented properly, you should be able to run the motor at half the speed that would be possible with 24 volts. For the same load torque, the current would be the same as with 24 volts.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit tricky, because it depends on the application.

The BTS7960 is a brushed DC motor driver with PWM speed control, so I presume you have a permanent magnet brushed DC motor.

Compared to using 24 V, running the motor on 12 V will:-

1. Draw half the stall current and half the initial startup current.
2. Have half the torque output at stall.
3. Spin half as fast at the same PWM ratio.
4. Draw the same current for the same torque output.
5. Draw twice as much **supply** current at the same speed with the same load.

For example if it needs 50% PWM to get the required speed on 24 V then it will need 100% PWM on 12 V, drawing twice the power supply current for the same power output (torque*rpm). This is necessary because power = voltage * current, so at 12 V the current must be doubled to get the same power input.

If the motor is geared and you change the gear ratio to get the same speed then it may draw twice the current *or more*, depending on where on its efficiency curve it is operating.

If the motor is driving a load with very high startup torque (eg. a piston pump or compressor) then it may not have enough torque to start up - and so will stay stalled drawing much more current than it would at 24 V.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the motor current will be same as 24V (not doubled). The motor speed will be half of rated speed. Power will be half of rated power. But there are lots of details. If you have the motor and power supply just try it. If you don't have the motor and power supply, select components with the same voltage for best results.